# Is there any reason to sanitize user input if the input is not going to be stored anywhere?

Tags: php

I can understand why user input that will be stored in a database needs to be sanitized to prevent sql injection and the like. But for a standalone script that just returns temporary data back to the user based on there original input. Is there a need to sanitize the user's original input in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't filter inputs; filter outputs. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694/how-do-i-html-encode-all-the-output-in-a-web-application/60690#60690).

Answer (score 2):

Look up [XSS Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Never give text to the user that you have not sanitized. The only "safe to not sanitize" string is the string you discard - pretty much anything you do with a string has a vulnerability somewhere unless you are careful.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer such a question.
Nobody knows your particular situation.

There can be a case where no sanitization needed, and there can be a case when sanitization required. Depends on the way data being processed.

A fellow developer had a funny service on his site, like one you described here. And everything was all right. Time passed and he decided to add a blog and authorization to his site. And got his site hacked  immediately, based on trivial XSS attack through this old service.

Answer (score 0):

I would say so as XSS attacks only require someone to have access to print something to the screen.

For example a text field which then just displays what ever you entered on the screen will leave you open to XSS attacks.

I recently came accross the HTML purifier php library which you might want to look at.

http://htmlpurifier.org/