# PHP: Basic sanitzation that are still relevant today?

Tags: php

Some years back, I use to do something similar to this on top of my script:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase', 0);
ini_set('url_rewriter.tags', '');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);

function clean_input ($arr)
{
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $arr = array_map('addslashes', $arr);

    return $arr;
}

$_GET = clean_input($_GET);
$_POST = clean_input($_POST);
$_COOKIE = clean_input($_COOKIE);
$_REQUEST = clean_input($_REQUEST);
```

Are this still relevant today at least in PHP 5.2?

Moreover, what is the minimum basic sanitation stuff we need in today?

Comment: You shouldn't do any of it, in any version of PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694/how-do-i-html-encode-all-the-output-in-a-web-application/60690#60690

Comment: Magic quotes was deprecated in PHP 5.3, and removed in PHP 5.4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` on anything that enters your database.

`htmlentities()` on anything that exits your database.

The Security class that is bundled with CodeIgniter is quite good. I would suggest looking through it if you are curious what is considered production ready.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mysql db I would say use mysql_real_escape_string() to clean user input

Comment: Is that all that is ever needed?

Comment: As answered by Chris, mysql_real_escape_string is a great function to clean input before saving it to a DB.  When you pull data out for display purposes use htmlentities.  You are safe with those functions